# The detail of select producer and how to persuade other to vote for you?

Tags: dpos

I'm curious about the documentation referring to block producers. However none of the documentation concretely describes how to vote or how to become a block producer. It may be explained in the code, but I find that really hard to understand.

Comment: you just need to call the system contract to register yourself as producer

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-newaccount), to register yourself you can use `$ cleos system regproducer`:

```
$ cleos system regproducer

Positional Arguments

account TEXT - The account to register as a producer
producer_key TEXT - The producer's public key
url TEXT - URL where info about producer can be found
location UINT - Relative location for purpose of nearest neighbor scheduling

 $ cleos system regproducer accountname1 EOS1234534... http://producer.site Antarctica
```

Similarly, to vote producers, [the docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-voteproducer-prods) mention `$ cleos system voteproducer`

```
$ cleos system voteproducer prods someproducr1 someproducr2 someproducr3 someproducr4
```

There's no on-chain mechanism to persuade others to vote for you as far as I know*, so promotion needs to be done off-chain.

* I guess you could airdrop and send custom memos to encourage recipients to vote for you or something